# How to search for users based on reputation and badge?

Tags: support, badges, search, users

Is it possible to search for users with high reputation (say $>25000$) and NO Gold badges?

Comment: While I'm not surprise that there aren't any. I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that there are currently more than 20 users with >50k rep. and no [Electorate badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) (some of them having even >200k rep.)... Maybe they only vote on answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can go to [stack exchange data explorer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). There is a  [script](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/103916/top-users-with-no-gold-badges) for top users without gold badge.

Below is the list of top users without gold badge on our site as of September 24, 2017.

[image: her]

Comment: Thank you for the list, today I read a question answered by Fred (#2 in the list) and he got me thinking about this question